# Maven Pax Runner cannot parse provision file

Tags: java, maven, war, pax-runner

if I have a profile defined as follows in the Maven plugin:

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>org.ops4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-pax-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
             <provision>
                  <param>--log=debug</param>
                  <param>--platform=felix</param>
                  <param>--profiles=compendium,web,war</param>
             </provision>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

then I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.ops4j.pax.scanner.UnsupportedSchemaException: Provisioning scheme is not specified
at org.ops4j.pax.scanner.ProvisionSpec.<init>(ProvisionSpec.java:87)
at org.ops4j.pax.scanner.composite.internal.CompositeScanner.scan(CompositeScanner.java:156)
... 41 more
```

The plugin does not understands web an war profile. Why??